# adding text to marker in mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview

i have done a app in android on Map, in which i have to place markers on map at different positions by using `latitude` and `longitude`.I have read this [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) to place markers and successfully placed the `markers`.

But issue is "i have to add number inside the markers which are at different places"

how can i add number in the  markers? Is there anyway something like adding textview that displays number?

Please suggest me and solve my issue?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OverlayItem.setMarker(Drawable) along with different icons/images to achieve the effect.  It will be something like

```
Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker1);
OverlayItem overlayitem1 = new OverlayItem(point1, "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City1!");
overlayitem1.setMarker(drawable);
drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker2);
OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City2!");
overlayitem2.setMarker(drawable);
```